# Visual Studio Vb.net loaded dataset from oracle query missing or replacing first row of data

Tags: vb.net, oracle, datatable

I have a vb.net application program that is suppose to query a oracle/labdaq database and load the dataset into a datatable. For some reason the query works fine and there is no exception thrown, however, when I load the data it seems to be missing the first row. I first noticed the issue when I did a query for a single row and it returned zero rows when I checked the datatable's row amount during debugging. I then compared all my data sets to a data miner application straight from the oracle source and i seems to always be missing one, the first, row of data when I use the application.

here is the code... I changed the query string to something else to maintain company privacy

```
Private Sub CaqOnSQL(strFileDirect As String)
        Try


            Dim connString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("CA_Requisition_Attachments.Internal.ConnectionString").ConnectionString
            Dim conn As New OracleConnection With {
                    .ConnectionString = connString
                }

            Dim strQuerySQL As String = "SELECT * FROM REQUISITIONS " &
                                        "WHERE DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('12/10/2020','MM/dd/yyyy') AND " &
                                        "TO_DATE('12/14/2020','MM/dd/yyyy') " &
                                        "ORDER BY ID"

            conn.Open()

            Dim Cmd As New OracleCommand(strQuerySQL, conn) With {
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            }
            Dim dr As OracleDataReader = Cmd.ExecuteReader()

            dr.read()
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            dt.TableName = "RESULTS"
            dt.Load(dr)


            ExcelFileCreation(dt, strFileDirect)
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the line `dr.read()` - I believe this is where the first line is being skipped

Answer (score 2):

You should remove the line:

```
dr.read()
```

The call to `Read` is what is causing you to skip the first row, when combined with the DataTable Load method.

In addition, I have taken the liberty to make some additional changes to your code for the purposes of Good Practice. When using Database objects like Connection and Command, you should wrap them in Using blocks to ensure the resources are released as soon as possible.

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.TableName = "RESULTS"
    Using conn As New OracleConnection(connString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim strQuerySQL As String = "SELECT * FROM REQUISITIONS " &
                                    "WHERE DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE('12/10/2020','MM/dd/yyyy') AND " &
                                    "TO_DATE('12/14/2020','MM/dd/yyyy') " &
                                    "ORDER BY ID"
        Using command = New OracleCommand(strQuerySQL , conn)
            Using dataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                dt.Load(dataReader)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Note: Be wary of Using blocks when using a DataReaderas you may find the connection is closed when you don't want it to be. In this case, the DataReader is used entirely within this function and is safe to use.

Comment: For the record, you don't need to nest `Using` blocks when there is no code between them. You can use one `using` statement to create the command and the data reader, separating them with a comma.

Comment: @MarcusHerniquesj It's a pleasure to help, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted (with the green tick)